# Collect all inputs from Documentation Center

Tags: notebooks

Is it possible to collect all inputs programmatically from every function in the Documentation Center in a list and wrap them in a `HoldComplete`?

My case: With some fundamental functions modified, I would like run a test of all functions to see what function will fail to execute.

Comment: Use `NotebookImport` on Documentation directory restricting it to `InputCells`. It is quite slow but you only have to do it once.

Comment: keep in mind that some examples are meant to fail to show some issues or are just `Messages` related.

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the hint. In this case I may try to avoid importing the inputs from "possible issues", etc

Comment: You can but I bet it is not the only section where messages are generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use the `"DocumentationExampleInputs"` property of the `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` entity or [`WolframLanguageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) function.

**With `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` entity:**

```
EntityValue[Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Round"], "DocumentationExampleInputs"]
```

For more than one at a time you can use `"EntityAssociation"` to have the entities as keys.

```
EntityValue[RandomEntity["WolframLanguageSymbol", 2], "DocumentationExampleInputs", 
   "EntityAssociation"]
```

**Similarly for [`WolframLanguageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) function:**

```
WolframLanguageData["Round", "DocumentationExampleInputs"]
```

Getting all may take a few moments to download.

```
EntityValue[WolframLanguageData[], "DocumentationExampleInputs", 
       "EntityAssociation"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot more easier than extracting by hand.